# Problem with the free particle propogator

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In order to find the propagator for the free particle, one must take account of the degeneracy associated with this problem.  In order to do that, you switch to the momentum basis, and obtain the result:
$$ U(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |p\rangle\langle p|\exp \left[{\frac{-ip^2 t}{2m\hbar}}\right]dp $$
Now using basic u-substitution, and intuition on this problem, one can obtain the result:
$$ U(t)=\sum_{\alpha = \pm} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[\frac{m}{(2mE)^\frac{1}{2} }\right] |E, \alpha\rangle\langle E, \alpha|\exp\left[\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}\right]dE $$

This approach makes logical sense.  However if you start with the idea that $$ U(t)=\exp\left[\frac{-iHt}{\hbar}\right]$$ if you wished to find $\langle x|U(t)| x' \rangle$ you could expand this idea like so:
$$ \langle x|U(t)| x' \rangle= \sum_{\alpha=\pm}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\langle x|E, \alpha\rangle \ \langle E, \alpha|U(t)|E', \alpha \rangle \langle E', \alpha|x' \rangle dE'dE$$ 
Now $ \langle x| E, \alpha \rangle$ can be easily solved for by solving the eigenvalue equation for the free particle, namely $\frac{P^2}{2m}|E \rangle=E|E\rangle$, but in solving this last equation, I never get the $\frac{m}{(2mE)^\frac{1}{2}}$ term as seen in the second equation.  If someone could point out my error that would give me immense relief.

Comment: won't you get that from the term $\langle E, \alpha|U(t)|E', \alpha \rangle$ ? In the end, you compare $U(t)$ and $\langle x|U(t)|x' \rangle$ if I see it correctly?

Comment: I compare $\langle x|U(t)| x' \rangle$ and U(t) because in they appear the same in the integral expressions, with the only difference being the x bras and kets.  Also I calculated $\langle x|U(t)| x' \rangle$ and it comes out to be the dirac delta function times $\exp\left[\frac{-iEt}{\hbar}\right]$ without the extra term.